# Is it possible to semantically navigate Objective C in Windows?

Tags: ios, objective-c, windows, ide

I need to review and analyze some iOS (iPad) Objective-C source code and will not have access to a Mac for the duration of the project. I'm quite comfortable using a text editor to perform this task, but would like to be able to use the features of an IDE to help navigate the codebase. E.g. easy navigation from variables and types to their definitions/implementations.

Is this practically achievable under Windows?

I've looked around and don't consider this question to be a duplicate. Please consider that I have no specific need to compile and/or run the code, as an end, in and of itself. I will not be writing any code or designing any UI/UX. I simply want to browse around the codebase and perform some basic analysis, with a few extra tools above and beyond that of a simple text editor.

Comment: It may not be a duplicate, but surely you're aware that it's off topic due to: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow...

Comment: Have a look at Sublime, even if it's not the best at tracing variables

Comment: @mah I understand that others may feel differently, but personallly don't feel that off-topic rule was intended to cover this type of question. I'm largely aiming to determine whether this is even *possible* under windows. Surely this is really quite different to the stereotypical "What is your favourite X tool?" that the offtopic rule is intended to keep at bay. Perhaps there is a way I could rephrase this question. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know the intention of the tool rule, but I don't think I agree with your assessment; regardless I didn't vote to close.